# Area of a triangle $\triangle ABC$

Tags: geometry, triangles, area, median, triangle-centres

Let be $\triangle ABC$ a triangle with its area of $48\text{cm}^{2}$. $M$ is the mid of $[BC]$ and $P$ is the mid of $AM$. We know that $BP \cap AC = \left\{N\right\}$.
The question is: how to compute the $\triangle ABN$ area?

I tried to use that the area of $\triangle ABM = 24$ also I tried to compute the mid of $[AC]$ and to try to divide the triangle in more smaller triangles, but no success for the moment.

Any input will be really appreciated.

Comment: HINT. Draw from $M$ the parallel to $BN$, to show that $AN=AC/3$.

Comment: I believe you.  (And I see how the result follows quickly from this fact.) I just don't see how to prove this fact.  Can you give another hint as to why this is true?

Comment: @SelrachDunbar Use [Intercept theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) in triangles $AMK$ and $BNC$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the trick is to find $S_\Delta PNC=2S_\Delta PNA$.

Let's for simplicity, set the total area is a unit. So
$$S_\Delta PAB=S_\Delta PMB=S_\Delta PMC=S_\Delta PAC=\frac14.$$ Since $S_\Delta PNA:S_\Delta PAB=S_\Delta PNC:S_\Delta PBC$, that is to say $$S_\Delta PNA:\frac14=S_\Delta PNC:\frac12.$$
Also we know that $S_\Delta PNC+S_\Delta PNA=\frac14$
which means $S_\Delta PNA=\frac{1}{12}$.

Therefore the answer is $48/12=2\text{cm}^{2}$.